# How to properly take the discrete Fourier transform of a signal as well as calculate the power spectral density of the DFT?

Tags: rf, signal-processing, fourier, signal-theory, power-spectral-density

I'm getting conflicting answers on how to properly represent a DFT and normalize the results as well as calculate the normalized PSD of the time series. For background, I typically work with voltage or electric fields vs time. Below is my current understanding of the process. Any direction, confirmation, correction, or literature recommendations would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance!

*Also, I'm not very competent at writing markdowns but am trying to learn, I apologize for that inconvenience in advance as I could not get inline equations to work.*

Given a time series voltage signal V(t), and constant sample rate \$f_s\$, the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) would be calculated for each evaluated frequency indexed from 0 to k by the formula:

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]\left ( cos\left ( \frac{2\pi kn}{N} \right )-j sin\left ( \frac{2\pi kn}{N} \right ) \right )$$

Where:

- X[k] is the complex value output for the integer k
- N is the total number of samples in the time series V(t)
- n is the sample number between 0 and N-1 of the time series V(t)
- x[n] is the time series value of V(t) at index n
- j is the square root of -1
- evaluated once for each integer value of k
- in the case of windowing, each time series value would be multiplied by a value from 0-1 depending on the window, and these scaling factors will be denoted as \$w_n\$ later
- Source: [Discrete Fourier Transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)

The frequencies evaluated for the DFT are found using:
$$ f_{k}=\frac{kf_{s}}{N} $$
$$ k = \left[0:1:\frac{f_{s}}{2}\right ] $$

The frequency domain resolution (or step size) is found where k=1 or simply as:
$$ \Delta f=\frac{f_{s}}{N} $$

The magnitude of the complex output is found as:
$$ |X[k]|=\sqrt{Re(X[k])^2 + Im(X[k])^2} $$

That magnitude is then normalized by dividing by the square root of the number of samples:
$$ \left | X\left [k\right ] \right |_{norm} = \frac{\left |X[k]\right |}{\sqrt{N}} $$

The DFT is then plotted at each value of k where f is positive with y-axis units of Volts/Hz:
$$ f_{k} \text{ vs } \left | X\left [k\right ] \right | _{norm} \text{ from 0 up to } \frac{f_s}{2} $$

**Here is where I start getting a bit fuzzy on things and I may be wrong (as opposed to all the rest of this which I am only slightly more confident in and might still be just as wrong all the same, haha)**
To convert the DFT output to PSD, the un-normalized magnitude is squared. Source: [How to Normalize A PSD](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32187/what-should-be-the-correct-scaling-for-psd-calculation-using-tt-fft/32205#32205):
$$ \hat{X}\left [ k \right ] = \left| X \left [ k \right ] \right |^2 $$

And the normalized PSD is calculated as:
$$ PSD\left [ k \right ] = \frac{2 \hat{X}\left[ k \right ]}{f_{s}S} $$

Where S is defined as the sum of squares of the windowing coefficients \$w_n\$:
$$ S = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w_n^2 $$

In the case where no windowing is used, all values of \$w_n\$ would be 1 since this is technically the same as applying a rectangular window.

The normalized PSD is now in units of Watts/Hz. To convert to dBm/Hz, the formula is the typical multiply the measured values by 1000 to convert PSD[k] from Watts to milli-Watts then:
$$ dBm\left [ k \right ] = log_{10}\left( \frac{PSD \left [ k \right ]}{1 mW} \right ) $$

Finally, the normalized PSD can be plotted in y-axis units of dBm/Hz as:
$$ f_{k} \text{ vs } dBm\left [ k \right ] \text{ from 0 up to } \frac{f_s}{2} $$

Is this process/math correct? Any correction, confirmation, or literature recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

*Edit: Fixed some variable inconsistencies*

Comment: I'm not going to answer as I don't want to wade through the maths carefully enough, but on a quick skim reading, normalised PSD, starts off in units of volts2/Hz, to get to watts/Hz you need a resistance. And, normalisation of some random FFT function is conventional, it could be 1/N, it could be 1/sqrt(N), it could be 1, depending which precedents the writer follows. I always run a known sinewave through the entire algorithm to check. Otherwise, all you've written looks plausible.

Comment: To provide an example for what @Neil_UK says: You need different normalization if you are interested in correlated signal amplitudes (like sine wave amplitudes) or uncorrelated wideband noise power

Comment: @tobalt I'm not sure I'd call that a difference in normalisation, just a difference in how you interpret the per-bin power values. When my intuition falters, [Parseval's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) always comes to my rescue.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses! Thank you for posting the edits as well Neil. I tried for hours to get the in-line equation formatting to work. I'll do some more reading into Parseval's theory. I'm always down to explore another rabbit hole haha. Thank you Tobalt for the suggestion of testing my algorithm on a sine wave as well! That sounds like a good practice that I will definitely be using from here on. I'm a student presenting to professionals so I want to ensure my work is accurately calculated, clear, and consistent. Thank you for the advice!